# hive multiple queries not working

Tags: select, join, hadoop, hive

I am trying to do something like this in HIVE:

```
insert into table abc 
select a.plc,b.direction 
from (select c.plc from test t JOIN central c ON t.id = c.boxno) a , 
     (select c.direction from test t JOIN central c ON t.id = c.boxno) b;
```

Please suggest what's wrong in this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel this query can be modified to obtain the result in a better way. Try this instead:

```
insert into table abc 
select c.plc,c.direction 
from test t
JOIN central c ON t.id = c.boxno;
```

Wont the required output be same? In case you are trying to achieve something else functionally, please elaborate.

Comment: i am basically trying to select columns from two table central and test. I have to check whether id from test matches with boxno from central ,as you can see from my query. the solution you posted wont work here. please suggest something.

Comment: Isn't `from (select c.plc from test t JOIN central c ON t.id = c.boxno) a , 
     (select c.direction from test t JOIN central c ON t.id = c.boxno) b;` same as `from (select c.plc,c.direction from test t JOIN central c ON t.id = c.boxno) a;`?

Comment: the bigger problem is that i have 7 columns in my abc table. In that case, do i need to add 7 select statements?

Comment: you did not answer my above question?

Comment: your query is working fine.Thanks.  i also did the same. But, as i said i have 7 columns in my abc table. How should i proceed then.

Comment: add all of them in the Select similarly..it should work.